# How to dismiss a view controller and return to it's parent view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a popup view from another view controller with an XIB file. It launches from a parent VC (`detailViewController`) and but the dismiss code is within its own VC (`KNThirdViewController`)

I'm using this code: https://github.com/kentnguyen/KNSemiModalViewController/blob/master/KNSemiModalViewControllerDemo/KNThirdViewController.xib

When this is called from (`KNThirdViewController`)

```
- (IBAction)dismissButtonDidTouch:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

The app returns to the `rootViewController` and not the `detailViewController`. It should simply dismiss itself (the `KNThirdViewController` popup VC) and return the user to `detailViewController`.

The view controller is presented with:

```
-(void)scriviBtnPress {

// You can also present a UIViewController with complex views in it
// and optionally containing an explicit dismiss button for semi modal
[self presentSemiViewController:semiVC withOptions:@{
 KNSemiModalOptionKeys.pushParentBack    : @(YES),
 KNSemiModalOptionKeys.animationDuration : @(0.5),
 KNSemiModalOptionKeys.shadowOpacity     : @(0.3),
 }];
```

}

Comment: Show how you are presenting the views.

Comment: show your code because as u discribed in your question, after dismissing it return to detailViewController not to rootViewController.

Comment: @Student It returns to the root vc not the detail vc as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` method is deprecated in iOS 6.0. why don't try with `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`

Comment: thanks! but that is not going to fix the problem I'm having. My current method works - it dismisses the vc but goes too deep and returns us to the root vc instead of the detailvc

Comment: Well, are you presenting the modal VC from a Navigation controller or you push your modal VC from another modal VC? If it is latter case, it sounds like your VC are stacked away until it reaches the root VC.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221510/dismissing-modal-view-controllers?rq=1. This post involves issue similar to yours i guess. No accepted answer but you can have a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this :

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```